# redirect after tweet - share through twitter implementation for website

Tags: html, twitter, sha

I am implementing social media share buttons in my website. Instead of popup, I like to redirect user to the social media pages for sharing. Once they share the content, possibily a redirect to my website.

I did this for facebook using url redirection method as given [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog)

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?
  app_id=145634995501895
  &display=popup
  &href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2F
  &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fexplorer
```

It is working fine. redirect_uri takes the user back to my website once sharing is done.

I am looking through [twitter guide](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/tweet-button/guides/parameter-reference1) for similar implementation. I understand that I can do similar implementation by redirecting to `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet` with necessary query parameters.

But i could not find any parameter for redirecting back to my website. Is this expected or any way to implement it? Thanks.

Comment: Does not look like they are offering that kind of feature.

Comment: Twitter web intents open as a popup, so there should be no need to redirect back to the website, as it will still be open in the background.